# Binomial expansion for solving american put option identity

Tags: binomial-coefficients, finance

For american put option I have to prove that:

1) As $D$ tends to $\infty$, $a_n$ tends to $-r/D$ so that $S^*$  tends to $0$.

2) As $D$ tends to $-\infty$, $a_n$ tends to $2D/ \sigma^2$ so that $S^*$  tends to $E$.

I have simplified the question posted here [american put option](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361096/american-put-option)

to the point where 
$a_n =\frac1{\sigma^2}\lim_{D\to\infty}[-\sqrt{D^2 + 2 r \sigma^2} + D]$.

I think to prove  1) and 2) above I have to do a binomial expansion on the square root keeping only the first two terms in the expansion

I am not sure how do I go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like an obvious auto-duplicate and as such, should be closed. I posted a full answer on the other page, using only the conjugate quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac12x+O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$, hence
$$\begin{align}D-\sqrt{D^2+2r\sigma^2} &= D\cdot\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{2r\sigma^2}{D^2}}\right)\\&=D\cdot\left(\frac{2r\sigma^2}{D^2}+O(D^{-4})\right)\\
&=\frac{2r\sigma^2}D+O(D^{-3})
\end{align}$$
as $D\to+\infty$.
By the same reasoning, 
$$D-\sqrt{D^2+2r\sigma^2}=2D+O(D^{-1})$$
as $D\to-\infty$.

Comment: Hi Hagen, Please can you elaborate on the second one? 
By the same reasoning, 
$$D-\sqrt{D^2+2r\sigma^2}=2D+O(D^{-1})$$
as $D\to-\infty$.